# Inserting Data in Postgres table when another table has been inserted with multiple rows

Tags: postgresql

I am new to Postgres. My problem is that I want to insert some *new rows* in "target table" when these *new rows* are inserted in a "source table".
I wrote a trigger to do exactly that but whenever the source is inserted with say *7 new rows* then the trigger inserts *7x7 = 49 rows* in target. Next if I insert *3 more new rows* in source then the target becomes *49+3x10 = 79*. 
What am I doing wrong..??

Trigger function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.rec_insert()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$  
BEGIN  
INSERT INTO target_table ("TIME","REGION","CITY","DISTRICT","Population")
SELECT NEW."TIME",NEW."REGION",NEW."CITY",NEW."DISTRICT",(100*(NEW."SAMPLES_MALE_Available")/(NULLIF((NEW."Total_AVAIL"-NEW."Female_AVAIL"),0)))
FROM source_table;
RETURN NEW; 
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And my trigger is

```
CREATE TRIGGER ins_same_rec  
AFTER UPDATE  
ON source_table
FOR EACH ROW  
EXECUTE PROCEDURE rec_insert();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must omit the `FROM`. Thats the reason because many rows are inserted (one for each row in the previous state of the table)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.rec_insert()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$  
BEGIN  
INSERT INTO target_table ("TIME","REGION","CITY","DISTRICT","Population")
SELECT NEW."TIME",NEW."REGION",NEW."CITY",NEW."DISTRICT",(100*(NEW."SAMPLES_MALE_Available")/(NULLIF((NEW."Total_AVAIL"-NEW."Female_AVAIL"),0)));
RETURN NEW; 
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Thanks it works. So earlier it was like insert the whole table for each row. It make sense now.